# How to save formatted text (which is not in RichTextBox) to the file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, text

I'm creating my own, similar to the `FlowDocument`, object model for representation of formatted text document (it's need me to complete my lab). And I want to have a possibility to save/load my document as/from ".rtf"-file (or file of another common text format). Are there any good ways (without explicit using RTF-code characters) to implement this?

> P.S.: The **main task** is creating a formatted text editor. But there are some constraints: **not to use** already existing text-controls (RichTextBox, etc.) and also **not to use** FlowDocument (I should create my own model instead). So I chose to use `TextFormatter`. And my `TextSource`-class should be based on my model of text document.

Comment: Is this an interview/course assignment? TextRange doesn't have any content, it's a *selection* of a document's content. It doesn't save anything itself either. If you want to know what it does, check [its code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextRange.cs). .NET Framework code is available as a reference. You'll see that it used a different class to handle serialization, and it only works with XAML content

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I'm university student. And this is just my lab/assignment.

_"You'll see that it used a different class to handle serialization, and it only works with XAML content "_ - So it just takes XAML-representation of FlowDocument and converts it to RTF?